# Javascript adding integers and decimals

Tags: javascript, arrays, decimal

I have a function where users can enter numbers like "5", "10", "0.47", "0.5" etc.
And every time the user enters the data, the data is saved in an array.

I am using the following code to **Add all the numbers** in the array:

```
    $scope.uTotal = uMiles.reduce(addPrice, 0)

        function addPrice(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
```

The above code adds all the numbers successfully but if a user enters decimals values it does not add the decimals values.

**For Example**:

The values in the array currently are below, this was collected by doing **console.log**:

[image]

The output on the screen after running the above function is:

**total = 5**

but actually it should display **total = 6.88**

How can I make sure that no matter what number the user enters its added up and displayed on the front it exactly.

Comment: `return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);` should do the trick.

Comment: @entropic Apologies for the earlier comment, your answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: You are concatenating strings. For example, `["5","0.47","0.47"].reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0)` returns `"050.470.47"`. Are you sure you get `5`?

Comment: I'm a bit curious why you're storing those values as strings in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) inside the function and you should be good:

```
function addPrice(a, b) 
{
    return a + parseFloat(b);
}
```

Comment: Why does JS parse the strings that are `< 1` as `0`? Where does the coercion to number happen? Where are the numbers truncated?

Comment: @Oriol, updated. I can't find the reference for that, so I've just removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your `addPrice` function, you use the operator `+` to sum the values.

But there is a problem: the values in the `uMiles` array are strings. Then, the [addition operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) `+` concatenates the strings instead of suming the numeric values.

To fix it, you must convert the strings to numbers.

- Before `reduce`, using `.map(Number)`:

  ```js
  uMiles.map(Number).reduce(addPrice, 0);
  function addPrice(a, b) {
      return a + b;
  }
  ```
- Inside `addPrice`, using the [unary + operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6):

  ```js
  uMiles.reduce(addPrice, 0);
  function addPrice(a, b) {
      return a + +b;
  }
  ```